# What is meant by "collateral" in dictionaries?

Tags: morphology, abbreviations, dictionary

Lewis & Short often use the abbreviation *collat.*, standing for *collateral* according to the appendix of abbreviations. An example:

> *ŭtĕrus, i*, m. (**collat**. form *ŭter*, Caecil. ap. Non. 188, 15; neutr. **collat**. form *ŭtĕ-rum, i*, Plaut. Aul. 4, 7, 10, acc. to Non. 229, 33; Turp. and Afran. ib.) [Sanscr. uttara, later; Gr. ὕστερος; cf. Gr. ὑστέρα, womb; Sanscr. udaram, belly; Engl. udder], the womb, matrix (syn. volva).

It is often used for the form of some word. I suspect it simply means "alternative". But the English word itself can also mean "descended from the same stock, but in a different line" in family relations. So what does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

Judging by examples, it seems to indeed mean "alternative".
Etymology offers a reading of "collateral" that fits the context perfectly:
Combining *con* and *latus*, one can form an adjective *collateralis* which means essentially "side by side".
Compare with the plain [*lateralis* in L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=lateralis&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
If two forms of a word are used side by side, they are alternatives to each other.

Comment: That was also my reading. But I'm wondering whether some 'official' explanation or a source outside of L&S exists.

Comment: @Cerberus I would like to see something more official as well. The conclusion seems fairly evident, but a reliable description of the word or use in other dictionaries would make the case much stronger.

Answer (score 2):

The *Oxford new American dictionary* defines as 'additional but subordinate; secondary: *the collateral meanings of a word*.'

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, “collateral” means “alternative” or “secondary”. Actually, this entry bears witness to the limitations of the venerable L/S. The references for the “collateral” uter are dubious (post-classical grammarians). Current etymological thinking is that uterus is  certainly not cognate with uttara- or ὕστερος,  nor with udder, though it is possibly cognate with Skt. udara-, with an inner-Latin shift of *-der- to -ter-. English udder belongs with Latin uber (IE -dh-).

Comment: Interesting, is the supposed Latin shift of "der" to "ter" related to some sound change like dr > tr? I think I remember seeing that mentioned somewhere as a Latin sound change (e.g. https://books.google.com/books?id=s7LuNvgfv0IC&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113&dq=Latin+sound+change+dr+tr&source=bl&ots=FSzNYttnDI&sig=gvI64cYoXf4Mwq-1kG-ENzP4scQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUruiLlcXYAhUd24MKHQuJDaYQ6AEIRDAI#v=onepage&q=Latin%20sound%20change%20dr%20tr&f=false) , but I didn't realize it could happen even with an intermediate vowel between the d and r.

Comment: @sumelic. The etymological dictionaries (Walde, de Vaan) offer different versions of the idea that the voiceless -t- in uterus developed by analogy to a (hypothetical) syncopated stem *uderV > *udrV > *utrV .